# How can I make records only update after they are approved

Tags: approval-process

Requirement is that a user can update the values in an account record (Short Text, boolean, number), and then that doesn't actually update the record until it has been approved by the owner.

More specific info is that those fields are pulled by our website and made public. We want to make sure that if those fields are changed, that they are still appropriate for being displayed on our website, therefor they need to be approved.

When I try to do this using an approval process, the fields are always updated immediately. On top of that, if it is rejected I can't make it go back to the prior values in some cases (text field).

Is there a way to make approval process work the way I'm intending, or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: The obvious solution is to double up the fields (add custom fields that represent the OOTB ones you want to handle in this way) and have the user edit these fields (and not see the real ones). Then have a trigger/process builder flow copy these field values across from the custom fields to the real fields when the approval happens.

Comment: This makes sense, and I probably should have thought of it. This particular approval has like 60 fields, so I think I wasn't allowing myself to see that as an option.